# How to move selected files one folder to another folder with sub folder also

Tags: linux, shell, perl, copy, move

This is my code to move files or copy the files.

```
#Here $directory = www(so the directory will create like this RubbishBin/www/) 
my $takingDir= "RubbishBin/$directory";
#@missingFiles= www/c2.html and www/image/1-3.gif 
my $createDir = `mkdir -vp $@ "$takingDir" && cp @missingFiles "$takingDir"`; 
say ("By Default Folder taking: RubbishBin");
```

I want to move this file into `RubbishBin` folder.

My output come like this

```
RubbishBin/www/c2.html
RubbishBin/www/1-3.gif
```

But my question is how can I create folder inside `RubbishBin/www/`. Also, it is not necessary next folder is `image`. It will different like `Download` or `video`.

I want output like this

```
RubbishBin/www/c2.html
RubbishBin/www/image/1-3.gif
or 
RubbishBin/www/Download/b.gif
```

After `www/` my script will select automatically create that folder and move that file like above output.

Comment: Make a template directory structure with the missing files and then simply use `rsync -a missingFilesTemplateDir/ RubbishBin/ww/` to copy the template to the destination directory?

Comment: @StefanBecker how can i make template for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move files and sub directory in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365537/how-to-move-files-and-sub-directory-in-perl)

Comment: @Shawn nope I try that one but not coming anything

Comment: what is the purpose of `$@` in `mkdir -vp $@ ...` ? In perl `$@` usually contains the exception string in case of an exception was thrown in an `eval` block.

Comment: The entries in the `@missingFiles` array should not contain the `www` prefix since it is already included in the `$directory` variable?

Comment: Have you looked at tools like [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) or, if you are restricted to using only core Perl modules, [File::Copy](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) and [File::Path](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html)? They have several methods to copy, move, create, and delete files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of how you can create the same folder structure under both the source (`$directory`) and the destination path (`$takingDir`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename qw(dirname);
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(rcopy);
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);

my $directory = 'www';
my $takingDir= "RubbishBin/$directory";
my @missingFiles= qw(c2.html image/1-3.gif); 

for my $name (@missingFiles) {
    my $dirname = dirname( $name );
    my $dest_path = catfile($takingDir, $dirname);
    make_path( $dest_path );
    my $source_path = catfile( $directory, $name);
    rcopy( $source_path, $dest_path ) or die "copy failed: $!";
}
```